# android Navigation Bar hiding and persantage of usable screen overlap

Tags: android, height, width, uinavigationbar, android-fullscreen

My problem is about persantage of usable screen . My application working well normally but ı assume that if ı change dimension of screen (for example galaxy s8+) it is down.

this is how is working fine

[image]
**strong text**

and this is the wrong one

[image]

the problem related with NavigationBar.
I tried to set MACHPARENT params and normally I use programmatically  DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        width = metrics.widthPixels;
        height = metrics.heightPixels - Utils.getStatusBarHeight(getContext());  this code. But it is not working in Galaxy s8+ when I hide navigationBar.
Does anyone can help me what is my fold?

edit.
I mean height of my screen doesnt work.

Comment: did you ever find the answer to this question? I am running into the same issue. The S8 nav bar messes up my app's measurements. The UI doesn't look right at all anymore.

Comment: please post here if u've found any solution to this problem

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and could solve this with the decorview:

```
    //Get the correct screen size even if the device has a hideable navigation bar (e.g. the Samsung Galaxy S8)
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView(); //if you use this in a fragment, use getActivity before getWindow()
    Rect r = new Rect();
    decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
    int screenHeight = r.bottom; // =2220 on S8 with hidden NavBar and =2076 with enabled NavBar
    int screenWidth = r.right; // =1080 on S8
```